# how do I host domain name on amazon ec2 windows instance using IIS7 server

Tags: iis, amazon-ec2, dns

I have domain name in network solutions. I'm using amazon EC2 windows instance in order to host my domain on EC2 
I created a new hosted zone for my domain in `Route53`. The zone file gave me name servers which I applied to my registrar.

Then, in EC2, I created an elastic IP address and associated it with my instance. I then created a new record set in my zone file and put the IP address down as an `A-Record`.

After this I pointed my domain to name servers given by amazon route 53:
when I type my domain name it is showing could not find the page.

I have searched and realize that I need to setup IIS 7 in amazon EC2 instance. I have tried but it is not connected to my web pages. My `webproject` folder in `downloads->mainpro`. I'm using `netbeans` to code my web application. Can you please tell me the step by step to setup the IIS7 server in EC2 instance?? so I can view my web pages through my domain name. And I don't have hosting service in network solutions. I have only domain name. Do I need hosting service in network solutions?
please help me out..
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you need to install IIS. On your server, go to Server Manager=>Add Roles and Features. Under Server Roles there will be one called Web Server(IIS). Install that. There will be a section labeled Application Development, if your site is coded in PHP (just assuming from you using netbeans) you'll want to check the CGI application development. You should also install PHP separately if it is in fact a php website.

Once that's installed start=>run "inetmgr" to launch IIS. You should be able to see a Default Web Site under the Sites branch. The directory for this web site is under C:\inetpub\wwwroot. You should be able to delete everything in that folder and upload your code. Back in IIS click Default Web Site then Browse *.80(http) to view your website.

Now to link your domain, go to Route53 and create a record set. Make it a type A with the value being your IP address and the name being your domain name without www. Now add another A type record for your domain name with www and your IP address as the value. Then in IIS right click on your website and click edit binding. Add your domain name with port 80 for all unassigned. Then add another binding with your domain name with www for port 80 and use all unassigned.

You can also watch this youtube video to help in setting up IIS. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wgkp6smOzi8

Comment: thanks..but i am using jsp and servlet for my project am not using php.Also in my ec2 instance iis server is already installed.I will try these steps immediately.

Comment: That's probably the biggest issue, setting up IIS for jsp and servlets isn't the easiest thing in the world. You'll have to configure IIS to use the JK ISAPI redirector plugin to send jsp and servlet requests to Tomcat. Here a document that should help you configure IIS for jsp and servlets. http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/iis.html

Comment: Thank You very much for your answer.I changed backend to php.It works fine.